# Storage Spaces cache in RAID 1

Tags: cache, intel, refs

I have 2 x Intel S3700 200GB. I want to employ ReFS and Storage Spaces, Mirroring to the drive, behaving like RAID 1. That's all i need, not more.

Now i plan to use this as database. Normally in RAID controller i have a choice between write through and write cache. I always pick write through for safety. I understand that S3700 has power loss protection and proven in some review i read.

My question how does cache works in Storage Spaces ? Do we have to set our own cache manually or it depends on SSD cache internally ? I have only one aim, i want the windows to report when the data has been physically write to disk, write through mode.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ribao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in "RAID1" mirrored spaces, you don't need to worry about caching.

---

WriteBackCache is a mechanism that is intended to be used with faster drives (NVMe or SSD) to speed up writes against the slower drives (HDD or SSD).

Therfore a write operation will look like:

1. write to write back cache (WBC)
2. optimize writes for second level storage [second tier] (after aligning stripes and so on)
3. write back to second level

Also - when using tiered storage spaces with optimization (and/or pinning) - most often used data get's migrated to the faster tier, to deliver optimal performance for most of the requests.

---

To finally answer your question (again):

Don't worry about caching.
Unless you're not enabling power-protected mode on your storage pool (which isn't the case by default), all operations are persistet when they are reportet as persitet.